# Clean and build an Eclipse java project with one click

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to clean and build a java project in Eclipse with one click? I don't want to go to Project -> clean -> OK and than to project menu 'Build project'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need something more powerful than clean and deploy, I suggest to learn  Ant build tool.
http://ant.apache.org/

Just configure it for your project and prepare the build script, than configure the build script for the clean and build target. If you need, also to deploy it on your server (glassfish, weblogic or whatever you want). With Ant you can configure more situation (test, production..)

Answer (score 14):

In Project->Clean I select "Clean projects selected below", select my project(s) and check "Start a build immediately" with "Build only selected projects".

Then go to Window->Preferences->General->Keys, search "Build clean" and enter my own binding for this command. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Then, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and Enter I have clean and build.

Answer (score 9):

When you have

```
Project --> Build Automatically
```

checked, it will be automatically rebuilt after cleaning it.

Comment: but it also rebuilts after every Ctrl + S

Comment: without cleaning, and only the saved file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually one case is simple when you rerun a configuration ( like testNG called on all tests or called on all classes of some package) .
Eclipse remember  a configuration.
When rerun : the configuration it may can be buggy if you have removed some classes so tesng give an excep^tion ( cant find class)
SOLUTION : just redo your configuration. ( destroy and recall).

Answer (score -1):

Select your project and goto menu bar:Select Windows then->Select Preferences then ->Select Keys then ->Select Build and Clean

Comment: Keys ? Where is this option ?

Comment: where is the keys there ?

Answer (score -3):

Just need to `Ctrl + S` then `Build`, it will be as good as new!

Comment: It will just build... Won't "Clean".. OP wants to Clean and build