# how can i fix my dimension in my project android?

Tags: android

I've a dimensi.xml (this is for my dimension). Initially this is not make an error, but suddenly my eclipse tell me about an error. It says "**Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output**". What the meaning with that? How can i solve that?

this is my code for my dimension

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- untuk layout maqdis -->
<dimen name="width_gambar_maqdis">250dp</dimen>
<dimen name="height_gambar_maqdis">100dp</dimen>
<dimen name="size_splash_maqdis">50dp</dimen>

<!-- untuk layout tahsin_awal -->
<dimen name="width_allbutton_tahsin_awal">135dp</dimen>
<dimen name="height_allbutton_tahsin_awal">50dp</dimen>
<dimen name="text_size_allbutton">15sp</dimen>

<!-- button 1 pada tahsin_awal -->
<dimen name="marginLeft_button1_tahsin_awal">35dp</dimen>
<dimen name="marginRight_button1_tahsin_awal">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="marginTop_button1_tahsin_awal">300dp</dimen>
```

error at "**dimen name="size_splash_maqdis**""
console say "**values\dimensi.xml:7: error: Found text " " where item tag is expected**"

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild again?

Comment: how to clean and rebuild again?

Comment: Is it a gradle build?

Comment: @ThomasR. i just try to right click in my project and choose source --> clean up, but that error not fixed

Answer (score 1):

**`Project -> Uncheck the "Build Automatically"`** menu.

And then from there you can find other menu will be enabled. Use `"Project -> Clean..." to clean your project, use "Project -> Build Project"` to build your project, and **`"Project -> Build All"`** to build all your projects at once.I hope it will help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547055/clean-and-build-an-eclipse-java-project-with-one-click